# How do I upgrade Grails app from 2.3.8 to 2.4.0.RC1?

Tags: grails

I have installed Grails 2.4.0.RC1 on my ubuntu 14.04LTS, and tried to 'run-app' the app which I've built with Grails 2.3.8 on mac 10.7.5.

First, Grails told me to 'grails upgrade' to upgrade Grails.
So I did, but Grails says "'upgrade' script is not found."
Oh? Ok, then I have manually edited the 'application.properties' and set "app.grails.version=2.4.0.RC1".
Tried 'run-app' once again, good, compile begins, but fails.
Seems like it's happening in "scaffolding" sort-of class.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the output you get when the compile fails?

Answer (score 3):

The `upgrade` command is not available anymore in Grails 2.4. Instead, the procedure for upgrading is detailed in the user documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

I also suggest you use the last version available which is Grails 2.4.0.RC2 at this time.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken, new one is: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading take care of few plugins that are not updated yet. So for that case you might have to use some static resource (e.g. below) as inline

---

Static Holder Classes

The following deprecated classes have been removed from Grails 2.4.x:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.support.GrailsResourceLoaderHolder
```

These static resources has to be removed from applicationContext.xml as below

---

```
 <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
</bean>
```

Assest pipline has taken over resources plugin.